# Omnichannel: how can I remove Presence Statuses?

Tags: omnichannel

I have an org where I have previously configured some **Presence Statuses**. I have worked on it, triggering some changes in status.

Now I want to delete all the statuses to debug my integration. When I try to delete them manually, I can't because they are being referenced by **User Presence** objects. If I click on the related User Presence object, I can't view it and I get an "Insufficient privileges" error (with an admin user).

I tried to delete all these User presences with some anonymous apex:

```
List <UserServicePresence> l = [SELECT Id FROM UserServicePresence];
delete l;
```

But I get an error when deleting them:

> Line: 2, Column: 1 DML operation DELETE not allowed on
>   UserServicePresence

Approach B: I tried to update them, by doing:

```
List <UserServicePresence> l = [SELECT Id FROM UserServicePresence];
for (UserServicePresence usp: l) {
    usp.ServicePresenceStatusId = null;
}
update l;
```

And I received this error:

> Line: 3, Column: 1 Field is not writeable:
>   UserServicePresence.ServicePresenceStatusId

Is there a way to delete these Presence Status objects?

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you'll have to do a few other things before you can remove them. First, remove the permission sets you created for your Users that gave them access to their Presence Status for each channel that you have a Presence Status enabled. Then, go to Setup and remove the Service Channels that are enabled to disable them under `Setup>Customize>Omni-Channel>PresenceStatus`. You may also need to disable any Serice Presence Routing Channels you have as well. I think that should allow you to do what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

According to a commenter on this idea https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdncrUAB/permission-to-delete-unused-presence-status

```
Shubham Bangad (Salesforce) July 29, 2021 at 1:27 AM
First, you can retrieve the presence configuration via Metadata API in workbench
Now, You need to create a destructive package by referring to your retrieved file. And push it off again via Workbench
```